# Hosting two Node.JS apps on same domain

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I have two node js applications I am running on the same box and I would like for it to run the first node js app for all routing except if the url is www.domain.com/blog to go to the other node js application.  Is this even possible with this setup or do I have to setup subdomains and use nginx or something?

Comment: Yes, this is very much possible using a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using nginx as a reverse proxy.

Assuming you have your blog node process running on port 3000 and another node process on 3001 a simple config would look like;

```
upstream blog {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}


upstream other {
   server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location /blog  {
        proxy_pass          http://blog;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   tcp;
        proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy       true;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://other;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection          "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   tcp;
        proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy       true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I try this my main node server works just fine, however my other one shows some promise but not quite there. When i go to /blog I get a "404

Page Not Found

Go to the front page →" Then when I click go to the front page it sends me straight to localhost:3000.  So clearly there is some link there.  One caveat is I removed default_server proxy_protocol from the listen line because when it was there it broke, is this related?  Also note I pretty much copied and pasted what you put there verbatim and threw it into my nginx conf file.

Comment: Make sure your node servers are configured to serve everything as if they are running from root, because from the node server's perspective, it is the root. Links in html however will need to be based on the out-side url, so, from /blog.

Comment: Looking at the logs when I hit the /blogs endpoint here is what I get: Blog App Log: GET /blog 301 0.571 ms - -
GET /blog/ 404 9.134 ms - -   Regular app log: GET /ghost/css/ghost.min.css?v=9b05545ca1 200 2ms
GET /ghost/img/404-ghost@2x.png?v=9b05545ca1 200 2ms.  Should both servers being hit on this request?

Comment: @user1200387 have you setup the `upstream`'s correctly ?

Comment: Do I need to add more then what you put in your answer?

Comment: You just need to makes sure that the upstream configuration is correctly pointing to the port the node processes are starting on

Comment: Ok then it must be something else.  Is there anything on the node side that I have to configure to ignore all "/blog" requests because it still prints log statements on both node processes when I hit "/blog"

Comment: For those with the "Cannot GET //api" error, just use `location /blog/` instead of `location /blog`